# How to get component meta data fields and values using core service? Please provide examples

Tags: core-service, 2013-sp1, metadata, component

Tridion2013. Can someone provide example of core service code retrieving list of metadata fields of a component from multiple folders. Instead of hardcoding the metadata field name, I would like to retrieve all metadata fields from the component.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Tridion and welcome to stackexchange. The best way to get a good answer is to follow the guidelines around asking. Here is a link to get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

So now you got the metadata xml of the component, the Tridion core service role is over; it's all about compiling the xml and get the desired things out of it using .net.

So assuming you want to get the values of metadata fields, you can follow the below example code, I haven't run it though so you may need some adjustments as well.

```
doc = XDocument.Parse(component.Metadata);
xmlData = doc.Root;
var elements= xmlData.Descendants();
 foreach (XElement element in elements)
 { 
   //get the value using element.Value
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many core service code examples available in the Tridion Practice Cookbook. You can browse through them here:  https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice?files=1

There are also many online blogs and q&a here with code samples too. Have a browse through, and if you still are stuck, let us know what exactly it is you're stuck on and we'd be happy to help.

Comment: thanks for the help. I got some progress and getting component data correctly but metadata fields are coming as below.. <Metadata xmlns=\"23232322323232\">
<a>Text-A</a>
<a>Text-A</a>
<c>Text-C</c>
<d>Text-D</d>
<e>Text-E</e>
<e>Text-E</e>
<g>Text-G</g>
<h>Text-H</h>
<i>Text-i</i>
<j>1999-02-01</j>
<k>2015-07-30</k>
</Metadata>  few elements are duplicate (e.g. <a>) in this. not sure how to get these values. I got the metadata values by XElement xMetaData = XElement.Parse(component.Metadata); I need to put the values in proper format.